# Javascript array serialize function for use in php

Tags: javascript, arrays, serialization

I have this javascript function which converts a javascript array into a serialized string for use in php as array.

```
function js_array_serialize(a) {
  var a_php = "";
  var total = 0;
  for (var key in a) {
    ++ total;
    a_php = a_php + "s:" + 
      String(key).length + ":\"" + String(key) + "\";s:" + 
      String(a[key]).length + ":\"" + String(a[key]) + "\";";
  }
  a_php = "a:" + total + ":{" + a_php + "}";
  return a_php;
}
```

The function above does the work for associative array. But I have a multi-dimensional array and something must be done in the for loop, i can think of an other nested loop.

My javascript array is of this structure:

```
var a = {
   'index': {
     'subindex1': 'default',
     'subindex2': 'default'
   },
   'index2': {
     'subindex1': 'default',
     'subindex2': 'default'
   }
};
```

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried turning the array into JSON, that way both PHP and javascript can use it with ease.

Comment: It's ok via php, I just need to do it via client side without the use of ajax or php to generate the serialized string.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be reinventing the JSON wheel. How about this:

```
function js_array_serialize(a) {
    return JSON.stringify(a);
}
```

The `JSON.stringify` function is natively built-in modern browsers. And if you want to support legacy browsers simply include the [json2.js](http://www.json.org/js.html) script to your page.

Never use string concatenations to build JSON. There are much more cases that you will need to handle: things like properly escaping the values. Think for example if the value contains quotes? It will break your serialization algorithm.

Comment: Now would be a good time to point the asker to an article about [Data Exchange Formats](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_exchange)

Comment: But that doesn't serialize the string as php function serialize($a).

Comment: @user558134, you could use json_encode and json_decode in PHP.

Comment: I know, I was thinking not to use ajax

Comment: @user558134, JSON doesn't mean AJAX at all. JSON is a standard and interoperable data exchange format which could allow you to communicate data between different systems (in your case that is javascript and PHP).